# SoftEther VPN not allowing clients to connect using AD credentials

Tags: vpn, active-directory, windows-authentication

We are trying to get SoftEther VPN to work on a SBS 2003 domain but it is rejecting apparently valid user credentials. (The server application is running on our actual SBS 2003 domain controller and the clients are all Windows 7.)

Does anyone here have any experience with SoftEther VPN, in particular, using it with AD authentication?

Comment: If you're going to vote a question down, at least have the courtesy to say what's wrong with it in a comment.

Comment: Instead of simply voting a question down, try taking 10 seconds to write some feedback in a comment so the OP can adjust the question so it no longer offends your sensibilities.

Comment: Unfortunately, enterprise hardware or software questions are off-topic here—please try [sf] instead. See the [help/on-topic] for details. (Please don't cross-post—if you post your question there, you should delete the question here.)

Comment: Thanks, except SoftEther VPN is *not* an enterprise VPN solution. It's a free, *open source* VPN solution (look it up - it's just a Japanese university research project). 12 other people have asked questions on SuperUser regarding SoftEther VPN (do a quick search) and they received useful answers and no petty downvotes for spurious reasons.

Comment: The problem is not the VPN, but the environment in which it is used. We're talking about Windows Small Business Server and Active Directory, which indicates use in an enterprise or business environment. As such, the question belongs on [sf].

Comment: Well, I think the people at Server Fault would say that "Small Business" belongs _here_. (…Though to be honest, they would probably say that _all_ businesses below a million users belong here. They're _picky_, to put it mildly.)